# Definite article with abstract nouns

Tags: articles, definite-articles, abstract-nouns

Is there a way one can determine whether to use the definite article before an abstract noun? For example:

> - little room **for imagination**
> - such concepts **as subjectivity and imagination**
> - the power of **the imagination**.

Why is there no article in the first two examples? I'm aware that 'the' points to a specific instance, and it is clear to me why one would say

> **the** imagination of the author or 
>   **a** reticent imagination.

However, in all the three examples that confuse me **imagination** is used in a general sense, and yet it takes the definite article in the 3rd instance.

Comment: It is optional in the third case, and probably the first as well.

Comment: Amazing that we've never discussed this subject before.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140896/definite-vs-none-article-before-abstract-concept-again

Answer (score 1):

The definite article serves to specify a particular instance.  It is used to mark an object as before mentioned or already known, or contextually particularised (OED).

Abstract nouns are not, by definition, particular to a time or place.